# $http JSONP request results in 404 on Chrome/Firefox, works correctly in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp

I'm developing a simple Hangman application using the [random word API](http://randomword.setgetgo.com/).  The author says that it's JSONP compatible.

See this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1t8ur23p/7/

The relevant code is here.  This is working correctly in IE and I'm getting a random word every time.  But I'm getting a 404 in Firefox and Chrome and I can't tell why.

```
function getSecretWord() {
  //call the random word API using JSONP request
  $http.jsonp(
      'http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'
  ).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      //apply the random word to the local secret word
      $scope.word = response.data.Word;
      //setup the other parts of the game
      $scope.letters = response.data.Word.split("");
      $scope.answerArray = response.data.Word.replace(/./g, '-')
          .split("");
  }).catch(function(response) {

      //debugging... see the contents of the faulty response
      $scope.error = response;

      //there's been an error, just default the word to 'hello'
      $scope.word = 'hello';
      $scope.letters = $scope.word.split("");
      $scope.answerArray = $scope.word.replace(/./g, '-').split(
          "");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running your code on a HTTPS page? Because this seems to be a [mixed content page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content) issue. I'm seeing the following error on Chrome and Firefox:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/1t8ur23p/7/show/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://randomword.setgetgo.com/get.php?callback=angular.callbacks._0'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

This happens when you try to load a HTTP page from a HTTPS page. You can see that if you run the code from http://jsfiddle.net/1t8ur23p/7/ (http, not https), it works fine.

Comment: Ahh... that was it.